# Why is static class instance going to null during await?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I've got a partly finished Xamarin solution that is working in Android. I'm trying to add UWP support (which I do understand is not quite all there yet). I call State.RestoreSystemIndex() in the code below. I have a breakpoint on the first line, and I can see that CurrentSystem is populated (as I would expect). I step through the code, and when `return await SecureStorage.GetAsync(key)` completes, CurrentSystem is now null, and of course the reference to it fails. What would make CurrentSystem go to null during the `await SecureStorage.GetAsync(key)` ?

```
    public class Configuration
    {
        public const int SystemIndexUndefined = -1;

        public int SystemIndex = SystemIndexUndefined;
        /* etc. */
    };

    public static class State
    {
        public static Configuration CurrentSystem = new Configuration();
        /* snip */
        private static async Task<string> OurGetAsync(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return await SecureStorage.GetAsync(key);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Logger.LogMsg($"Exception {ex} thrown by GetAsync({key})");
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static async void RestoreSystemIndex()
        {
            string s = await OurGetAsync("SystemIndex");
            if (s == null) CurrentSystem.SystemIndex = Configuration.SystemIndexUndefined;    // Not recorded
            else CurrentSystem.SystemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        }
        /* etc. */
```

Comment: I split the return await into two statements, string s = await GetAsync() and return s. The static is going to null during the await, not the return. FWIW, the debugger shows the await GetAsync() taking 1293 milliseconds.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition running on Windows Pro 64 bit.

Comment: Have determined that it only happens the second and subsequent time I run the project in VS. If I quit VS and restart it then I can run the project successfully *once*.